# Android Virtual Device Machine has stopped

Tags: android

I am beginner in Android development, so I am watching tutorial and follow the steps, but the program does not go well.

I imported `v7 appcompat` in my project. (But there was problem with v21 file,  but I changed from 19 to 21 in project.properties, so that is fixed.)

However, when I extend Activity class in my Java file, the AVM works fine, but when I extend ActionBarActivity, the AVM keep saying "Unfortunately program has stopped."

Here is the java code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Calculator extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    }

}
```

Here is xml code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:entries="@array/left_navigation"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left">
    </ListView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

***Additional***
LogCat information is here:

```
02-18 02:38:12.125: D/AndroidRuntime(3041): Shutting down VM
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041): Process: example, PID: 3041
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:147)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at example.Calculator.onCreate(Calculator.java:15)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/example-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     ... 17 more
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):         ... 18 more
02-18 02:38:12.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: When using `ActionBarActivity` you need to add proper style in the manifest too.

Comment: Which theme are you using? Wait.. Post your LogCat first!

Comment: Okay, can you show me more detail on that?

Comment: @Tushar Okay, I added LogCat.

Comment: Did you add `v7 appcompat` jar or library?

Comment: @FabinPaul I can see that there is "android-support-v7-appcompat.jar" in Referenced Libraries folder.

Comment: try deleting that file.

Comment: @FabinPaul You mean delete that jar?

Comment: Yes. try deleting that jar. and clean your project

Comment: @FabinPaul I did and there are bunch of compile time error came out in my Java File.

Comment: Now try importing `v7 appcompat` from directory         ~SDK\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat and           right click on your project>properties>Android>add library appcompat

Comment: And I hope your support repository in SDK Manager is updated

Comment: @FabinPaul Okay. I followed all steps, now it says "Could not find program.apk!" when I run the file.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project? and try rt clicking your project>properties>Java build Path>remove any jar which is not present in project or has been deleted

Comment: @FabinPaul I did... I did one more time and still cannot find the apk...

Comment: Did your `v7 appcompat` compile without errors?

Answer (score 0):

"You need to use a `Theme.AppCompat` theme (or descendant) with this activity." You are using the appcompat library as a Library Project, in which case you'll see the available themes under `res/values` in that project. you need to use a proper style too in the manifest.

To test you can add this in `application` node of manifest

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

Comment: After I did it, there is error message given. Error: No resource found that matches the given name.

Answer (score 0):

You extend ActionBarActivity if you'll be using the ActionBar on api s lower then 11 for support for api >=7 check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Also it can be a source of confusion but when you use ActionBarActivity your theme must be a child of one of Theme.AppCompact descendents such as

```
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompact">
           <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/accent_1</item>
           <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/accent_dark</item>
           <item name="android:colorAccent">#f00</item>

           <item name="colorPrimary">@color/accent_1</item>
           <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/accent_dark</item>
           <item name="colorAccent">#f00</item>
  </style>
```